# Operador de conversión de tipos entre instancias de clases plantilla

Tags: c++, template, conversión-de-tipos, operador-de-conversión

Estoy trabajando en un código confuso y propenso a errores; el problema surge al usar dos sistemas de coordenadas y confundir continuamente las coordenadas de uno de los sistemas con las del otro.

#### Problema.

La aplicación consiste en un juego 2d [Roguelike](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) de [vista cenital](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plano_cenital). El sistema de coordenadas del personaje, proyectiles, enemigos y atrezo del mapa (coordenadas de mundo) consiste en que cada número es una baldosa de la mazmorra; así la baldosa en la esquina superior izquierda empieza en la posición `{0, 0}` y se extiende hasta la posición `{0.9999…, 0.9999…}`<sup>1</sup>.

Dicho de otra manera:

- Valores `{[0, 1), [0, 1)}` pertenecen a la baldosa `{0, 0}`.
- Valores `{[8, 9), [3, 4)}` pertenecen a la baldosa `{8, 3}`.
- etc…

En cambio el sistema de coordenadas de pintado (pantalla) no se basa en baldosas si no en [sprites](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Sprite.php), pudiendo hacer zoom sobre la sala y situando la sala en posiciones diferentes según cómo apunte la cámara, nos encontramos que las coordenadas para **pintar** la baldosa `{x, y}` serían en realidad:

```
{x * ancho_sprite * nivel_de_zoom, y * alto_sprite * nivel_de_zoom} - vector_cámara;
```

Esto me causa problemas cuando a una función de pintado le paso una coordenada de mundo o cuando a una función de IA, lógica o físicas le paso una coordenada de pintado, cosa que me ha pasado más de una vez, dando lugar a errores difíciles de depurar.

#### Solución.

He pensado en crear tipos diferenciados para cada familia de coordenadas, y cuando las coordenadas viajen de un contexto a otro aplicar transformaciones de manera automática; es decir: de manera transparente al programador; o en el peor de los casos hacer que el uso de un sistema de coordenadas en el contexto incorrecto falle.

Para este objetivo estoy usando la clase plantilla [`Vector2`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Vector2.php) de [sfml](https://www.sfml-dev.org) y para hacer incompatibles unas coordenadas de un sistema respecto a las de otro he añadido un nivel más a la plantilla:

```
enum contexto : char
{
    mundo,
    pantalla,
};

template <typename T, contexto C>
struct coordenada : public sf::Vector2<T>
{
    using base = Vector2<T>;
    using base::base();
    using base::base(T, T);
    // Mas directivas using...
};
```

Con este sencillo truco evito usar de manera no intencionada coordenadas de un sistema en otro (código ilustrativo):

```
using Vector2fm = coordenada<float, mundo>;
using Vector2fp = coordenada<float, pantalla>;

struct jugador
{
    Vector2fm posicion_logica;
    Vector2fp posicion_visual;
    sf::Sprite s;
} j1;

void mover_con_teclado(Vector2fm &elemento) { /* ... */ }
void pintar_en_posicion(Vector2fp &elemento, sf::Sprite &s) { /* ... */ }

// ...

/* Error no existe conversion conocida
   de coordenada<float, pantalla> a coordenada<float, mundo> */
mover_con_teclado(j1.posicion_visual);
/* Error no existe conversion conocida
   de coordenada<float, mundo> a coordenada<float, pantalla> */
pintar_en_posicion(j1.posicion_logica, j1.s);
```

Con este truco, si defino correctamente los tipos de cada coordenada, me soluciona el problema de usar coordenadas de pantalla en mundo y viceversa.

#### Error.

Lo único que debo hacer es proporcionar los operadores de conversión en ambas direcciones:

```
enum contexto : char
{
    mundo,
    pantalla,
};

template <typename T, contexto C>
struct coordenada : public sf::Vector2<T>
{
    using base = Vector2<T>;
    using base::base();
    using base::base(T, T);
    // Mas directivas using...

    template <typename U>
    operator coordenada<T, mundo>() const
    { return { x / 2.f, y / 2.f }; } // El 2.f es ilustrativo

    template <typename U>
    operator coordenada<T, pantalla>() const
    { return { x * 2.f, y * 2.f }; } // El 2.f es ilustrativo
};
```

Pero esto provoca una alarma por cada función de conversión e igualmente falla al tratar de hacer la conversión:

> ```
> alarma: la función de conversión convirtiendo 'coordenada<float, contexto::mundo>' a si misma nunca será usada
> operator coordenada<T, mundo>() const { return { x / 2.f, y / 2.f }; }
> ^
>
> alarma: la función de conversión convirtiendo 'coordenada<float, contexto::pantalla>' a si misma nunca será usada
> operator coordenada<T, pantalla>() const { return { x * 2.f, y * 2.f }; }
> ^
> ```

La alarma aparentemente se da cuando una instancia determinada de la plantilla intenta generar conversión a si mismo... de momento no me causa molestia, lo que no entiendo es por qué sigue sin funcionar la conversión pese a haber creado (al menos) una función de conversión válida que no genera alarma:

> ```
> error: ninguna función coincide para llamar 'mover_con_teclado'
> mover_con_teclado(j1.posicion_visual)
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nota: la función candidata no es viable: no existe conversión conocida de 'coordenada<[...], contexto::mundo valor 0>' a 'coordenada<[...], contexto::pantalla valor 1>' para el primer argumento
>
> error: ninguna función coincide para llamar 'pintar_en_posicion'
> pintar_en_posicion(j1.posicion_logica, j1.s);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nota: la función candidata no es viable: no existe conversión conocida de 'coordenada<[...], contexto::pantalla valor 1>' a 'coordenada<[...], contexto::mundo valor 0>' para el primer argumento
> ```

#### Pregunta.

¿De qué manera debo definir el operador de conversión de `coordenada<float, mundo>` a `coordenada<float, pantalla>` y su inversa?

---

<sup>1</sup>La orientación de las coordenadas es la usada por [sfml](https://www.sfml-dev.org) en que `{0, 0}` está en la esquina superior izquierda y el eje `y` crece hacia abajo.

Comment: Revisa las traducciones que has hecho en el código `world`-`mundo`, `coordenada`-`context_vector`, ...

Comment: Gracias por el aviso @eferion :)

Comment: De nada, es que me he puesto a mirar el código y me estaba volviendo loco jejejeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se produce porque las funciones no aceptan una referencia constante:

```
void mover_con_teclado(Vector2fm &elemento)
```

Al hacer la conversión estás creando un rValue que se pasa como referencia a la función y eso no le está gustando demasiado al compilador.

Como un rValue no puede ser modificado el compilador descarta esa conversión y busca otra que sea viable. Al no encontrarla muestra un error y se queda tan tranquilo.

La solución pasa por bien usar una referencia constante bien pasar un objeto por valor:

```
void mover_con_teclado(Vector2fm const& elemento)
void mover_con_teclado(Vector2fm elemento)
```

Otra solución pasaría por convertir el rValue en un lValue y después llamar a la función:

```
void mover_con_teclado(Vector2fm &elemento);

Vector2fp a;
Vector2fm b = a;
mover_con_teclado(b);
```